# Keep getting 11 status left. when proccessing my image. Please help me

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to thumb images in a separate process while the server sends an HTTP response, so I'm `exec`'ing a PHP CLI script. When the script is run directly by CLI, it works fine; but when I `exec` it, Imagick forces the exit status to 11 despite my `exit(0)`. The latest point at which I can exit to prevent the 11 status is just before `flattenImages` is called.

- PHP CLI source: http://codepad.org/WTHOiWw0 (designed for execution either as ordinary PHP or via CLI)
- example CLI invocation: `php -f lib/php/thumb_test.php -- img=om3e2a`
- issue history: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255

I tried to minimize that test-case by taking out all the validation and database interaction, but when I tried the 11 status left.

Comment: How are you determining the exit status, please?  Log files?  Console information?  If so, can you give us the exact wording from the error, please?

Comment: I wish I had wording... :(

The exit status is assigned to the third argument to PHP's exec.

Comment: Can you actually do something with the exception you're catching, please. $e->getMessagE() or put some other echo in there and tell me if it's actually catching an exception from Imagemagic.

Comment: There is no exception thrown, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @relisys: How do you know, if you have no handling?

Comment: Which extension are you using, ImageMagick has 3 for PHP.

Comment: The exit status you're getting back from IM indicates SIGSEGV. I find it hard to believe theres no exception being thrown.

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't calling ImageMagick commands directly? Like `exec('convert ...')` or `exec('mogrify ...')`? That's how I always use ImageMagick.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The var_dump never runs, therefore no exception triggers the try-catch.  (I'm outputting the script's output, as assigned by reference from exec, via FirePHP.)

@Orbling: Imagick; sorry for not stating that in the post.

@vicTROLLA: Me too.

@Mark Eirich: I'm using the Imagick PECL extension, and I would wonder the opposite personally.  Why would I use exec rather than a PHP API?

Answer (score 0):

I finally thought to check Apache's error.log, and the 11 status was accompanied by this:
PHP Warning: Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

I found the solution here:
http://www.somacon.com/p520.php
Apparently I accidentally put an extra << extension="imagick.so" >> line in php.ini. Removing it allowed the CLI script to return status 0.